# Is there any way to get output of top 5 servers only among all hosts in ansible-playbook

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue ansible condition and loops:

I would like to get the output of top 5 servers only but the following playbook giving the output of all hosts instead of 2 hosts.

```
---
- name:
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name:
      command: hostname -i
      register: out

    - set_fact: my_ip = "{{out.stdout_lines}}"
      with_items: [1,2]
      when: item <= 2
```

output:

```
TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/ansible/mm.yml:9
ok: [s1] => (item=1) => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "my_ip = \"[u'172.31.45.164']\""}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": 1}
ok: [s1] => (item=2) => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "my_ip = \"[u'172.31.45.164']\""}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": 2}
ok: [ansible] => (item=1) => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "my_ip = \"[u'172.31.39.107']\""}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": 1}
ok: [ansible] => (item=2) => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "my_ip = \"[u'172.31.39.107']\""}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": 2}
ok: [s2] => (item=1) => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "my_ip = \"[u'172.31.37.172']\""}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": 1}
ok: [s2] => (item=2) => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "my_ip = \"[u'172.31.37.172']\""}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": 2}
```

Comment: When posting questions, please take a minute to read the formatting help in order to properly format code samples, program output, and so forth. I've edited this question for you.

Comment: Alright, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may not fully understand how Ansible works. When your play starts with this:

```
- hosts: all
```

This means that Ansible will run the tasks in your play on *each* of the hosts in your inventory. So if you have, say, five hosts in your inventory, then you're running these tasks...

```
    - name:
      command: hostname -i
      register: out

    - set_fact: my_ip = "{{out.stdout_lines}}"
      with_items: [1,2]
      when: item <= 2
```

...five times (so that second task will actually execute 10 times...five hosts, and for each a host a loop with two items).

Furthermore, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with that second task.  Given your loop (`with_items: [1,2]`), your conditional (`when: item <= 2`) will *always* be true, so it's not serving any purpose. And you're not use the value of `item` in the task.

If you want the hostnames of the first two hosts in your inventory, you could write:

```
- hosts: all[0:1]
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command: echo {{ inventory_hostname }}
      register: out

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

This would run those two tasks on the first two hosts in your inventory.  Given an inventory that look like this:

```
host1 ansible_host=localhost
host2 ansible_host=localhost
host3 ansible_host=localhost
host4 ansible_host=localhost
```

The above playboook would produce:

```
PLAY [all[0:1]] ******************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "host2"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you :) got the required output(I used conditions and loops to get the first 5 hostname so that's why when and with_items used in the playbook).